# Using 2 NIC in ESXi 4.1

Tags: vmware-esxi, routing, nic

We are planning to move all our physical server into 2 ESXi box. Currently each of the server has 2 NIC. One NIC is used as public interface which has public IP, and another NIC has private IP. All servers are in same private subnet. But the public interface has different gateway for different server.

The ESXi server has 2 physical NIC. Is it possible to use one of the NIC as public NIC for all guest OS and another NIC as private NIC? Is this also possible to use different gateways for guest OS? Thanks for you response in advance.

Comment: Had you considered setting up VLANs and setting up fault tolerance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it possible to use one of the NIC as public NIC for all guest OS and another NIC as private NIC?
yes, first one will be for one virtual switch for the guest machines, the second one only for esx

Is this also possible to use different gateways for guest OS?
yes, you specifiy the gateway in the guest

Answer (score 3):

In ESXi you map NICs to virtual switches, and then you connect virtual machines (or vmkernel) to them. So, yes, you can configure your networking pretty much as you want. The host's management network can be completely different than the one VMs are connected to.